# How to be able to have a loop generate different alphabet buttons with the same function?

Tags: c#, loops, button

I am currently doing an assignment on a hangman game, and have to code the buttons, is there a way to be able to code all buttons in a loop instead of having to code them one by one?

Here's how one of them looks like(I am using windows form btw):

(each button is a letter of the alphabet, with numbers it would be easier)

```
private void A_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    guess = "A";
    A.Enabled = false;
    GuessCheck();
}
```

Comment: Probably you have to specify the environment you are programming with. Usually it is different in HTML than in WPF or WinForms.

Comment: Example for WinForms (which appears to be what you are using): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131696/Easy-Code-to-Create-Button-Array

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
    private string guess = "";

    public void GuessCheck()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You clicked letter " + guess);
    }


    private void Any_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Button b = (System.Windows.Forms.Button)sender;
        b.Enabled = false;
        guess = b.Text;
        GuessCheck();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int top = 50;
        int left = 100;

        for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; ++i)
        {
            var b = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            b.Text = System.Convert.ToChar(i).ToString();
            b.Name = "btn" + b.Text;
            b.Left = left;
            b.Top = top;
            left += b.Width + 2;
            b.Click += Any_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(b);
        } // Next i 

    } // End Sub Form1_Load
```

VB.NET

```
Private guess As String = ""

Public Sub GuessCheck()
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString("You clicked letter ") & guess)
End Sub ' GuessCheck


Private Sub Any_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim b As System.Windows.Forms.Button = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button)
    b.Enabled = False
    guess = b.Text
    GuessCheck()
End Sub ' Any_Click


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim top As Integer = 50
    Dim left As Integer = 100

    For i As Integer = AscW("A"c) To AscW("Z"c)
        Dim b = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        b.Text = System.Convert.ToChar(i).ToString()
        b.Name = "btn" + b.Text
        b.Left = left
        b.Top = top
        left += b.Width + 2
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Any_Click
        Me.Controls.Add(b)
    Next i

End Sub ' Form1_Load
```

Comment: @user3154509: This is a good proposal. You can also position your buttons manually with the designer, implement `Any_Click` method and then assign the the Click event of each button to `Any_Click`